# What is the regex that accepts anything except a digit, or positive, negative digit?

Tags: python, regex

It should not allow:

```
1
2+
-3
4-
+5
```

It should allow anything other than that Eg: 1%, ^1, etc. it should allow. I was trying to do it this way:

```
^[%!@#$^&*()]\d[%!@#$^&*()]$
```

but getting lost in between. How do I do it?

**UPDATE:** `^(?:\d[^-+]|[^-+]\d)$` is what I needed.

Comment: Try `^(?:\d[^-+]|[^-+]\d)$` if you need to match 2-char strings with 1 digit and the other symbol cannot be `-` or `+`. To match any kind of strings other than those digit+sign, use `^(?!(?:\d[-+]|[-+]\d)$).+`

Comment: Don't update the question with the solution. Write the solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It seems you can post your comment as an answer. ndn IMHO you should have rollback the edit.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Thanks for pinging.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accept only non digit use `^\D+$`

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(?:\d[^-+]|[^-+]\d)$
```

It will match 2-char strings with 1 digit and the other symbol cannot be `-` or `+`.

**Pattern**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\d[^-+]|[^-+]\d)` - either

  - `\d[^-+]` - a digit and any char other than `-` and `+`
  - `|` - or
  - `[^-+]\d` - any char other than `-` and `+` or a digit
- `$` - end of string

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/27Qt4y/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
""" test with 1, 2+, -3, 4-, +5"""
a = "1-"
b = re.search("^\D+$",a)
if b:
   print b.group(0)
```

Comment: If I do 1%, it should allow but its not.